# Android app crashes at startActivity(intent)

Tags: android, android-intent, crash

App crashes while passing data to another activity through intent, the part of the code is as follows:

```
public class Walls extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.walls, container, false);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

       gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                //Create intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(Walls.this.getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

                //Start details activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

...

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DetailsActivity"/>
```

...

The app just crashes without any android default popup  i.e., "App has stopped"

Any idea what cud be the issue?

Comment: please post log error

Comment: the logcat logs are at following path: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GrL1i26yR7n476Z57izIwsJHi_0KX_X0

Answer (score 0):

Use on `getActivity()` for context of Fragment. It may be `NullpointerException` so print logs and check.

```
  gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

                  Log.e("title",""+ item.getTitle());
                  Log.e("image",""+ item.getImage());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you post your log , what type of error are you getting @SurendraSingh

Answer (score 0):

See return values of getTitle, getImage and getAvtivity. One of them must be returning null and hence the crash.

Comment: Return values are not null for getTitle, getImage and intent have the required extras as well.